# Recursively transform a JSON object to an array of key/value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, properties

How to turn a JSON To a properties array in JS, no matter what's the JSON's depth ?

**JSON**

```
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "baz": "UP"
        }
    }
}
```

**key/value properties**

```
{
  "foo.bar.baz": "UP"
}
```

### One-level solution

My current code only treats one level, instead of n:

```
var user = {name: 'Corbin', age: 20, location: 'USA'},
    key;

for (key in user) {
    if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " = " + user[key]);
    }
}
```

Thank you :D

Comment: Please post your existing code and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you @Archer, I've updated my question as you suggested it to me.

My current solution doesn't cover any JSON depth, that's my problem.

Comment: That's not JSON

Comment: Thanks @naomik, my bad ! fixed now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, if a member is an object, make a recursive call, otherwise, update the output object:

```js
data = {
    foo: "hello",
    bar: {
        baz: {
            qux: "UP"
        },
        spam: 'ham'
    }
}



function unwrap(obj, prefix) {

    var res = {};

    for (var k of Object.keys(obj)) {
        var val = obj[k],
            key = prefix ? prefix + '.' + k : k;

        if (typeof val === 'object')
            Object.assign(res, unwrap(val, key)); // <-- recursion
        else
            res[key] = val;
    }

    return res;
}

console.log(unwrap(data))
```